# how to check whether the given dictionary keys (API data) are of type Int : swift

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, key

This is myDictionary respond from API call:

```
 {
    "table" = [0 = ["b": "2"], 1 = ["b": "4"], 2 = ["b": "20"], 3 = ["b": "27"], 4 = ["b": "2015"], f = "0", s = "0", p = "10"]
 }
```

How to check whether the dictionary "keys" are available, and whether they are of type Int. How to check whether the given data can be displayed in a table view, with only the key of **1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5, 6 and further more increasing order** as the above dictionary can have furthermore keys && ***exclude other keys*** (asAbove: key: f, s & p) of dictionary *table* ..

Can anyone recommend me any examples please..

Comment: Your key is type of Int but it is in the form of String.

Comment: yeah but can't we check it using "\(Int)"  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     let keys = demo["data"]!["table"]!.keys

     for k in keys{
       var num = Int(k)
       if num != nil {
         print("Valid Integer")
       }
       else {
        print("Not Valid Integer")
      }
    }
```

Comment: I did the following as you suggested:
let keys = tblData.keys
                        for k in keys{
                            let num = Int(k)
                            if num != nil {
                                let keydata = tblData[k]!["bill_date"]
                                print(keydata)
                            }
                            else {
                                print("Not Valid Integer")
                            }
                        }

Comment: But it prints Optional(2016-07-26)
Optional(2016-10-27)
Not Valid Integer
Not Valid Integer
Optional(2015-12-29)
Optional(2015-07-27)
Optional(2016-11-22)
Not Valid Integer
Optional(2015-07-27)

Comment: Yeah it is going through the loop but some value are missing while in the loop. Why? and can we get the data in sorted form..

Comment: I just added sort method to keys 
let keys = tblData.keys.sort()
Now, everything is working good. Thankyou so much @john